# Azure Active Directory Multi-Factor Authentication with Conditional Access Policy not working

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication

We want to achieve Multi-Factor-Authentication on a per-user-basis using Azure Active Directory B2C. So every user can choose if he/she is prompted for MFA or not.

This feature used to be only available for Azure Active Directory but not for Azure Active Directory B2C. The only way to achieve this was to use [Custom Policies](https://www.kallemarjokorpi.fi/blog/azure-b2c-custom-mfa-implementation.html). But this is a route we would like to avoid at any cost.

So recently we figured that it's possible to enable MFA conditionally by enforcing a Conditional Access Policy.
We created a Conditional Access Policy and selected only certain users (for which we would like MFA to be active).
However, no matter what we configure in this Conditional Access Policy, it just doesn't make any difference. The only setting which shows any effect is the property "Multifactor authentication -> MFA enforcement" in the User Flow.

Is this just bad UI/UX in the Azure Portal and configuring a Conditional Access Policy for B2C tenants doesn't do anything or would it be possible to use Conditional Access Policies to configure MFA for certain users only in a Azure Active Directory B2C tenant and we were just using it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to enable Multi-Factor Authentication on Azure AD B2C:**

I have created Application for authenticating users with user flows on Azure AD B2C.

**Azure Portal > Azure AD B2C > App registrations > New registration > Name ex: Any Name > Supported account types > Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows).**

[image]

Create **User-Flow** with **MFA** enabled using **Conditional Access Policy**

**Azure AD B2C > User flows > New User flows > Sign up and Sign in**
Enable **MFA** with **Conditional Access Policy**

[image]

Create Conditional Access Policy per user like below.
**Azure AD B2C > Conditional Access > New Policy.**

Select the users who required MFA authentication.

[image]

**MFA Grant**

[image]

**MFA will prompt only per selected users on Azure AD B2C.**

[image]

**Verification Page**

[image]

If I tried login with **user3** account which is not enabled MFA, it's not moving to MFA registration page.

> Note: For testing I have enabled MFA only 2 accounts. **User1** and **User2**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. When creating a new tenant and testing it i can reproduce the expected behavior also you were showing. But after a couple of tests with signing in users i always get the MFA-Prompt, no matter if users are part of the Conditional Access Policy or not. It looks to me that those users are classified as risky because of my tests. I would like to prevent B2C being too smart and calculating a risk score. Is there a chance to have the conditional access policy being the only reliable deciding factor if the MFA prompt shows or not?

Comment: Yes, you can restrict Azure resources using CA by setting different factors,       
 Refer this link more about Conditional Access Policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It is basically working but i found out, if we select "Authenticator App" as second factor, every user is prompted for registering the Authenticator App, no matter if the CA policy evaluates as true or false (use is part of MFA-group or not). MS Support claims it should be possible but for now it was still not possible to find out how to bring up the registration-popup only for users that are part of the MFA-Group.

Comment: If you select MFA group while creating CA policy under the **user and groups section**, only those users will get MFA prompt while singing into the application.

Comment: This is true for users that have already registered authenticator app with their credentials. However, this initial prompt to register the authenticator app shows up for every user, no matter if part of the group or not. Newly registered users can't be part of the group at the point of registration but get prompted to register for authenticator. This is not acceptable for users that don't want to have MFA enabled.

Comment: (unless there is any magic setting to suppress this prompt for users that are not part of this group but I had a lengthy meeting with Ms support today and we could not find such a setting). It would be great to have it though because this could be a Blocker for us.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? We're facing the same issue right now... and it seems it is by design. 

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow#set-multifactor-authentication

Conditional - During sign-up and sign-in, users are prompted to enroll in MFA (both new users and existing users who aren't enrolled in MFA). During sign-in, MFA is enforced only when an active Conditional Access policy evaluation requires it: