# Azure AD B2C keeps asking user to enroll in MFA even if they are excluded from Conditional access policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an asp.net 4.8 web application integrated with Azure AD B2C.

External users will use local account in B2C tenant
Internal company users will use their own Azure AD access to log in to the system, so I added the Azure AD tenant as an identity provider

Users are created in the B2C tenant when a record is added in the web application via the graph API

I setup a Sign in user flow and put MFA as conditional and selected enforce conditioanl access policy

Then, I created a conditional access policy that requires MFA and exclude all external guest (The company users since they already have MFA registered via Azure AD)

The idea is to force the external users only to use MFA and skip the users who will log in with their exising Azure AD.

The problem now is that all users are seeing the enroll for MFA Authenticator app even if they use their external Azure AD credentials which they already have MFA app set up.

How can I skip the MFA enrolment for the company users? I put them in a group and explcitlty added that group to the Exclude list in the CA policy but it is not working

1. Added the user to a speccific group and excluded that group from CA policy
2. Checked the Audit Lots and it says that no conditional access policy was applied

I want to avoid custom policy as much as possible

Comment: Security default is off. We can't create a conditional access policy if it is ON

Comment: Does this [**condition**](https://i.imgur.com/Ry0CtJg.png) and [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/1oAqwNq.png) fulfill your requirement?

Comment: I already have those 2 conditions applied to exclude external/guest users and yet all external users (social identities) are asked to enroll in authenticator app eventhough it does not ask  them later for MFA.
What I need is to NOT ask them to enroll if the CA doesn't trigger MFA

Comment: Please check the comments by markus-s in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75086014/azure-active-directory-multi-factor-authentication-with-conditional-access-polic?rq=2. Maybe you have to implement custom policy to achieve it

Comment: Unforutnately it did not help as he is facing the same issue

Comment: Yes and I guess this can only be changed by using custom policy